# Not ablle to receive token from OAuth authentication in Apigee tool

Tags: apigee

I have created AccessTokenClientCredential and RefreshAccessToken in OAuth proxy through Apigee tool.
When I tried to access "https://damuorgn-prod.apigee.net/oauth/client_credential/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=07VoDotbGhyl3aG8GxjkyXivoTNH9oiQ&client_secret=fb8ZOrAUUSGp3FAv" URL after mentioning client Id and client secret ID, page is empty. It does not displays any error or displays with Token value.

Steps followed to create token from below URL
"http://apigee.com/docs/gateway-services/content/secure-calls-your-api-through-oauth-20-client-credentials".
Please advise.

Regards,
Damodaran

---

1. I tried both Test and Prod environment but there was no luck.
2. I have requested for Curl software installation. Is there any other way to test this URL without Curl software. Your immediate reply is appreciated. Thanks!

Curl https://damuorgn-test.apigee.net/oauth/client_credential/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials -X POST -d 'client_id=qnYUqb6j3uGraRAh7JF9d651nUXNwMCC&client_secret=mjHIFMcTDCa3YQ6f'

Could you please check on this link from Curl software ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there may be a couple of issues:

1. When I try your URL, I get a "CLASSIFICATION_FAILURE" error - which means the proxy can't be found. I noticed that you're using "damuorgn-prod.apigee.net" when you might have deployed your proxy to the test environment, and meant to use: "damuorgn-test.apigee.net".
2. In step 5.2 of the document you referenced, it says to use POST instead of GET. So you might try this:

   curl https://damuorgn-test.apigee.net/oauth/client_credential/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials -X POST -d 'client_id=07VoDotbGhyl3aG8GxjkyXivoTNH9oiQ&client_secret=fb8ZOrAUUSGp3FAv'

(When I try this, I get an "invalid client id" error, but maybe that client_id is no longer valid?)

Hope that helps,
Scott

Comment: Hi Damodaran. Hopefully you see this as I cannot comment on your answer above. I just tried and the curl command you pasted does work.  If you don't have curl available, you could use the [Apigee console](https://apigee.com/console/others). And if you would, please mark this answer as solved.